# Problem with openssl and accessing webpage via SSL/HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, synology

I have problem accessing my Synology DSM918 (NAS) over HTTPS sitting behind a router with public static IPv4 address with a domain pointing to it. The [network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqgvA.jpg) is in the picture.

The problem is that anytime I try to access the NAS from a computer (PC2) connected to wireless bridge everything works as expected.
However, when I try to access the NAS from a computer (PC1_ connected directly to the router, I am unable to access it using the domain name (I can connect only via local IP address).

I tried to investigate the issue and found following:

```
curl https://<domain-name> -v

* Rebuilt URL to: https://<domain-name>
*   Trying <ipv4-address>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <domain-name> (<ipv4-address>) port <port> (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to <domain-name>:<port> 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to <domain-name>:<port>
```

```
openssl s_client -connect <domain-name>:<port>  -msg -showcerts

CONNECTED(00000005)
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 00c3], ClientHello
    ...
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0059], ServerHello
    ...
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 09fc], Certificate
    ...
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = <domain-name>
verify return:1
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 014d], ServerKeyExchange
    ...
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0046], ClientKeyExchange
    ...
>>> TLS 1.2 ChangeCipherSpec [length 0001]
    01
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0010], Finished
    14 00 00 0c 18 f1 a3 91 fe 6d 91 a2 86 62 fd 81
4711933548:error:1401E0E5:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_FINISHED:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.260.1/libressl-2.6/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:585:
---
...
...
...
---
SSL handshake has read 3002 bytes and written 126 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: ACCB7A7AACFD5A838382B467FBFE26766E0D6147CAAE3A51FEE5A7B39BD84004
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 015E73F4347EF4954DA9FE58F5F34D73A662EDDEE9F7B4F8650977756EE2778DFB80F0C22ABF608B8CE55721578A9CA4
    Start Time: 1577712963
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Could anyone help me and point me to the right direction? To me, it seems like the router is somehow malforming SSL handshake.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Today, I got error `curl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: error:1401E0E5:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_FINISHED:ssl handshake failure, errno 0` but in a completely different context, so I don't know, if this is pointing you to the right direction. In my case, the problem was that the server with which I tried to perform a TLSv1.2 handshake couldn't read my public client key and then compare it with the client certificate and private key I offered it. The application running on the server needed a less restrictive read permission for my public client key.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that Synology has general problems with TLS. I was unable to get mails sent from Acronis via TLS on the same mail server (Mail Plus, Port 587). I even tried to configure "old TLS compatibility" and it didn't work. I had to stick with unencrypted mails on Port 25.

Apart from that: it also seems that the access rights to relevant directories are not always set correctly. I did a set up of a Git server during the last couple of days and had to walk through various instructions and posts until I got the correct configuration.